# Bootstrap Search Input Dynamically Center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a search box in a Bootstrap navbar. When I move the screen the content is in the center, but the search box is not. How do I make it so the navbar shifts to the center as the window shrinks or grows? **EDIT:** Here is a bootply of my navbar: http://www.bootply.com/3n1JFSOHPW

```
<div class="search" style="margin:auto; text-align:center;">
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" id="searchform">
        <div class="form-group" id="the-basics">
            <input type="text" id="searchbox" class="form-control typeahead" placeholder="Search TextNotes" style="border-top-right-radius: 0px; border-bottom-right-radius: 0px; margin:0 auto;" onfocus="change_button_color()" onblur="button_color_reset()" autocomplete="off" data-provide="typeahead">
        </div>
        <button id="searchbutton" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left:-4px;border-top-left-radius: 0px; border-bottom-left-radius:0px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
     </form>
</div>
```

Comment: for margin auto to work you must have a fixed width

Comment: just FYI, the `.navbar-left` class left-floats the element, but to really help you out, a working bootply or jsfiddle would be most helpful

Comment: If I set the max width then it does not grow with the website to always be in the center and if I set the fixed width, then it is oddly off center to the right....so I dont know what is going on

Comment: can you post the full code for your navbar? or put it in a bootply or fiddle?

Comment: @Ted http://www.bootply.com/3n1JFSOHPW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/SyzDMZgBzW)

Fixed the margin, set the max width a little lower, and set the width for the form.

The major changes are on these two lines:

```
<div class="search" style="margin: 0px auto; text-align:center; max-width: 400px;">
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" style="width:100%;" role="search" id="searchform">
```

HTH

-Ted